# Ubuntu, Apache, MariaDB, PHP and WordPress, Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception

Tags: wordpress

I bulit WordPress on Ubuntu, and when I try to connect WordPress, HTTP ERROR 500 occurred. And I read this in the log:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'wordpress.wp_options' doesn't exist in /var/www/html/wp-blog/wp-includes/wp-db.php:2056 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/wp-blog/wp-includes/wp-db.php(2056): mysqli_query() #1 /var/www/html/wp-blog/wp-includes/wp-db.php(1945): wpdb->_do_query() #2 /var/www/html/wp-blog/wp-includes/wp-db.php(2695): wpdb->query() #3 /var/www/html/wp-blog/wp-includes/option.php(284): wpdb->get_results() #4 /var/www/html/wp-blog/wp-includes/functions.php(1730): wp_load_alloptions() #5 /var/www/html/wp-blog/wp-includes/load.php(752): is_blog_installed() #6 /var/www/html/wp-blog/wp-settings.php(159): wp_not_installed() #7 /var/www/html/wp-blog/wp-config.php(97): require_once('...') #8 /var/www/html/wp-blog/wp-load.php(50): require_once('...') #9 /var/www/html/wp-blog/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('...') #10 /var/www/html/wp-blog/index.php(17): require('...') #11 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/wp-blog/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 2056
```

The version of Ubuntu is 22.04, Apache is 2.4.52, MariaDB is 10.6.12, PHP is 8.1.2.

I tried to enter /var/www/html/wp-blog/wp-includes/wp-db.php and view the code to find the problem. But I didn't find a problem.
Do you have any good ways to solve this problem？Thanks！

Comment: Look likes your database missing that table, reinstall your WP or restore your backup.

Comment: It looks like you are using an older version of WordPress.